# PHP SimpleXML: Get children of child node

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to make something that will retrieve photos and videos from a Picasa Web Album atom/RSS feed. The feed looks something like this:

```
<!--XML heading above-->
<entry>
    <gphoto:id>98387294</gphoto:id>
    <gphoto:description></gphoto:description>
    <!--More XML tags below-->
    <media:group>
        <media:content url="url here" type="video/mpeg4"></media:scontent>
        <!--more media:content tags-->
    </media:group>
</entry>
<!--more entry nodes below-->
```

What I want to do is go thru each entry tag, then go thru each media:group tag, retrieve a specific `media:content` tag based on its size attributes, and echo html code containing info from the tag. Here is my test PHP code below:

```
    //code to retrieve XML not shown
    $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlFormatted);
        foreach($xmlObj->children() as $entry){
            $size = sizeof($entry->children());
            foreach($entry->childNode[$size-1]->children() as $node){
                echo $node . "\t";
            }
            echo "\n";
        }
```

The code can looop thru each child of `$xmlObj`, however I cannot loop thru the child of each entry. I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function children() on boolean
```

The error is on the line with `foreach($entry->childNode[$size-1]->children()`. How would I loop thru the child of a child node? Or, how would I get the contents of `<media:content>` (which isn't a normal XML node because of the colon)?

This is my first time trying to make code that can interpret XML, so my methods might not look the best.

Comment: Why are you not using foreach() for the inner loop? Colons in the tag name separate the namespace prefix from the local name, read up about namespaces.

Comment: @ThW I never knew that the colons were called XML namespaces. This is my first time working with XML, thanks!

Comment: The colons are not the namespace - it is a little more complex. The syntax of a nodeName is `{prefix}:{localName}`, the prefix is an alias, look for an `xmlns:{prefix}` attribute. The value of that attribute is the actual namespace. A namespace is an globally unique URI. An URI tends to be long and "noisy", so the alias/prefix is used as a mapping for readability.

Comment: I have it mostly figured out now. I'm loading an XML document for each <entry> containing the info I need.